# Jquery, ordered form input and label with DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

Small problem. I want to set the labels to the left infront of the input boxes so they are within the same line.

Any help would be great.

My HTML:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="FNAME" id="FNAME">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="LNAME" id="LNAME">
 </div>
</div>
```

Jquery I have tried:

```
$('.row.col-12 label').each(function() {
  $(this).insertBefore( $(this).next('input') );
});
```

What the form looks like:
[enter link description here](http://media02.hongkiat.com/free-form-builders/form-builder-intro.jpg)

Some CSS:

```
form-group {
margin-bottom:15px;
}

.col-12 {
    width:100%
    }

.input-sm {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

select.input-sm {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

textarea.input-sm {
  height: auto;
}

.input-lg {
  height: 45px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

select.input-lg {
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
}

textarea.input-lg {
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use CSS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TWfDs/

Comment: The fiddle above which I simply copy and paste your DOM, the label is in the same line as textbox. Is that what you want or ???

Comment: Oh I wish, their is a lot of CSS attached to it too so at the moment the labels are situated on-top of the input boxes.

Comment: hmm... can you post your css too? Ideally css styling that are affecting the DOM part that you posted.

Comment: Thank you, I've added some of the CSS

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TWfDs/3/

Comment: After pasting the CSS, I still see that everything is in one line though.

Comment: I have added all the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/TWfDs/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to understand your problem but simply put your DOM into the fiddle, each label is in the same line as each textbox.

jsfiddle.net/TWfDs

But if you meant that first name and last name should be in the same one line, you can try below.

```
$(".row").css({"display":"inline-block"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TWfDs/1/

----- update ----

If you can still style via js and it is acceptable to set the static width for the textbox then label and textbox line up.

http://jsfiddle.net/TWfDs/10/

```
$("#FNAME").css({"display":"inline-block", "width":"300px"});
```